# How can I use different definition of class for different template type in C++? (Class Overloading?)

Tags: c++, templates, hashtable, overloading

What I want to do is making a hash table. To make it efficient, I want it to work differently depending on the type of the data. Ex : quadratic probing method for int, separate chaining method for string.

I found that I can use `typeid()` function to compare the `typename` of the template. I could use it inside the definition of the class, but I'm worried about it will slow down the program.

I feel something like "Class Overloading" can solve this problem. But I've never heard of "Class Overloading". What is the right way to solve this problem do you think?

Thank you.

Comment: Search for template specialization. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

Comment: Make the hash table class itself a template and specialize it per type as-needed (since you've already decided you're writing all that extra type-specific code anyway). Though honestly, potentially save yourself some time and see if `std::unordered_map` performs to your liking. You may end up saving yourself a ton of work.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunately the purpose of my assignment is making fastest hashtable without using std::unordered_map ㅠ.ㅠ

Comment: "type traits" are another, more fine-grained way to select implementation depending on the specific type, and can be used in combination with specialisation of larger templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"But I've never heard of "Class Overloading". What is the right way to solve this problem do you think?"*

You might use a template class and specializations (overloads) for it's interface:

```
template<typename T>
class hash_table {
public:
    bool probe(const T& x);
    hash_table<T> chain(const T& x);
};

template<>
bool hash_table<int>::probe(const int& x) {
    // int specific implementation
} 
template<>
bool hash_table<std::string>::probe(const std::string& x) {
    // std::string specific implementation
} 
template<>
hash_table<int> hash_table<int>::chain(const int& x) {
    // int specific implementation
} 
template<>
hash_table<std::string> hash_table<std::string>::chain(const std::string& x) {
    // std::string specific implementation
}
```

---

You can also have a bit more flexible variant using a base class to provide the interface, and a type based selector to inherit:

```
template<typename T>
class hash_table_base {
    virtual bool probe(const T& x) = 0;
    virtual hash_table_base<T> chain(const T& x) = 0;
    void some_common_code() {
        // ....
    }
};

class hash_table_int 
: public hash_table_base<int> {
    virtual bool probe(const int& x) {
    }
    virtual hash_table_base<int> chain(const T& x) {
    }
}

class hash_table_string 
: public hash_table_base<std::string> {
    virtual bool probe(const std::string& x) {
    }
    virtual hash_table_base<std::string> chain(const std::string& x) {
    }
}

template <typename T>
struct SelectImpl {
     typedef hash_table_base<T> BaseClass;
};

template<int> struct SelectImpl {
     typedef hash_table_int BaseClass;
};

template<std::string> struct SelectImpl {
     typedef hash_table_sting BaseClass;
};
```

---

```
template<typename T>
class hash_table
: public SelectImpl<T>::BaseClass {
};
```

As for the latter proposal, you may even going to extend this to a [Policy based design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design) pattern.